# Angular 1.x consuming outer scope within directive template body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Given a third party directive `tpd` with isolate scope (closed source for argument's sake), take the following markup for example:

```
<div>
    <tpd>
        <div>{{tpdScopeField}}</div>
        <div>{{outerScopeField}}</div>
    </tpd>
    <div>{{outerScopeField}}</div>
</div>
```

This will output something similar to:

```
<div>
    <tpd>
        <div>tpdScopeFieldValue</div>
        <div></div>
    </tpd>
    <div>outerScopeFieldValue</div>
</div>
```

**How can one communicate effectively with the outer/parent scope in markup?**

Another example would be trying to call a function (on-something event) of the outer scope:

```
<div>
    <tpd>
        <button ng-click="outerScopeEventHandler(someArgs)">Click me!</button>
    </tpd>
    <div>{{outerScopeField}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the property is available in parent, this code will do:

```
<div>
    <tpd>
        <div>{{tpdScopeField}}</div>
        <div>{{$parent.outerScopeField}}</div>
    </tpd>
    <div>{{outerScopeField}}</div>
</div>
```

And similarly `$parent.functionToCall(args)` will call the parent scope method.

Comment: See, that's what I thought. But it's working for the field, but not for the function. Do you have a working example?

Comment: After trying this out a bit more, I've discovered my issue (which applies to fields and functions as expected). If using ng-if on any of the parent elements, a new scope is created, requiring additional `$parent.` prefixes (eugh).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this with $parent. But I think you shouldn't do this with $parent. If this directive, tpd, is a third-party directive, you should use [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators).

You can modify it by using decorator. For example, you can add another attribute to this directive. And you can pass custom data from your parent $scope.

I said these. Because using $parent is an anti-pattern and sign of bad architecture.

__

Additional to your comment; if new isolated scope is because of ngIf, you can use controllerAs for your $parent scope.

__

An example for decorator;

```
angular.module('yourApp')
  .config([ '$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('tpd', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
      var directive = $delegate[0];

      angular.extend(directive.scope, { 
          othervar: "=" 
      }); 

      return $delegate;  
    }]);
  }]);
```

Comment: Can you provide a decorator example?